# How to fix Null Pointer Exception when create connection to database on Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I want to create a second repository. I clicked on the New button at the connection window and created a new database connection which should contain my repository. Testing the database connection worked (test button said it was o.k.).

But know when I try to login with admin/admin the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.initializeVariablesFrom(Database.java:4590)
at org.pentaho.di.repository.Repository.connect(Repository.java:626)
at org.pentaho.di.repository.Repository.connect(Repository.java:608)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoriesDialog.ok(RepositoriesDialog.java:505)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoriesDialog.access$900(RepositoriesDialog.java:73)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoriesDialog$11.widgetDefaultSelected(RepositoriesDialog.java:378)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoriesDialog.open(RepositoriesDialog.java:427)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openRepositoryDialog(Spoon.java:5361)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.selectRep(Spoon.java:5418)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:5548)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:412)
```

I can normally login into my already existing repository.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug. Did you create the repository (SQL button)

Comment: I created a transformation, after that, I click "Database connection" to add connection to mysql and get error below!

Comment: Does the bug persist when you work outside a repository (disconnect from the top-right button on the menu bar).

Comment: It took place when I create a connection to database MySQL.

Comment: Does the bug persist when you work outside a repository (disconnect from the top-right button on the menu bar) ?